# Laravel creating a package composer error

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, workbench

I'm trying to create a package through the terminal, using artisan but I keep getting this error message 
Package workbench created!
sh: 1: composer: Too many levels of symbolic links

the vendor folder is not created thus there's no ServiceProvider class.

```
carlos@carlos-Satellite-P775:/opt/lampp/htdocs/packs$ php artisan workbench redpanda/testPack --resources 
Package workbench created! 
sh: 1: composer: Too many levels of symbolic links 
carlos@carlos-Satellite-P775:/opt/lampp/htdocs/packs$
```

Comment: Where are you executing it? What command did you use? Do you have something in app_base/workbench ?

Comment: carlos@carlos-Satellite-P775:/opt/lampp/htdocs/packs$ php artisan workbench redpanda/testPack --resources

Package workbench created!

sh: 1: composer: Too many levels of symbolic links


carlos@carlos-Satellite-P775:/opt/lampp/htdocs/packs$